# "Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web" But I am not using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net MVC 5 web site that is using Entity Framework and SQL for the database. When I publish the site to my host and run it I now get an error about MySql.Web.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The error message also focus on this line from the machine.config

```
     <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" 
type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, 
    MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" 
connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" 
enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" 
requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" 
requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" 
maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" 
minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
 passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
```

I do not use MySql in my project and can not find any references to it in any of my configuration files.
I have read some other posts on SO that talk about adding the MySql connector to my configuration but don't understand why I would need to do that if I don't use MySql anywhere??

Comment: It looks like someone installed the MySQL Connector on your machine.  You should be able to remove providers from your app using a `<clear/>` or `<remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider" />` in your web.config.  Do you have a membership provider section you can post?  (obfuscate all sensitive data, please)

Comment: I had no membership section in my web configs. So I added one and explicitly removed the MySQLMembershipProvider as you suggested and all works well. Thanks

Comment: Post as answer so I can accept and you get credit. :)

Comment: Done. Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like someone installed the MySQL Connector on your machine.

You should be able to remove providers from your app using a `<clear/>` or `<remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider" />` in your web.config.